# How to remove a border or a line that is at the top of a bottom navigation bar using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I need to get my bottom navigation bar without the line or the border that is at the top of a navigation bar.It needs kind of to be as a part of the main screen.Help me guys using Kotlin,thank you in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple on your `BottomNavigationView` simply add `app:elevation="0dp"`:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    app:elevation="0dp" />
```

That will make it change from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]